# Solr "Error adding field" during POST where a column has NULL values too

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":176},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","java.lang.NumberFormatException"],
    "msg":"ERROR: [doc=fc396e71-4b97-4ae5-bf31-2ccd0953d6d3] Error adding field 'seasonNumber'='\\N' msg=For input string: \"\\N\"",
    "code":400}}
```

The file to be indexed is a .tsv file and 2 columns (seasonNumber and episodeNumber) have integer values but also Null values denoted by `\N`

I tried to add following lines to `managed-schema.xml` but to no avail :

```
<fieldType name="seasonNumber" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="true"/>
<fieldType name="episodeNumber" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="true"/>
```

My post command is:
`./post -c imdb -host *hostname* -params "separator=%09" -type text/csv ~/imdb-dataset/title.episode.tsv`

Can someone please help in this?

Comment: It would probably be better to define an updatechain that removes the field if the value is `\\N`: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/update-request-processors.html - or preprocess your field to replace any \N values with an empty value (if those are accepted by the CSV import endpoint). Keeping the season/episode numbers as integers will give proper sorting, instead of text which would sort them `1`, `10`, `11`, `2`, etc.

Comment: Cannot we load the data without cleaning the data? Like handling multiple values for same field: Eg: 1,\N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding:

```
<field name="seasonNumber" type="text_general" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="episodeNumber" type="text_general" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

to managed-schema.xml

Basically the type should be: text_general.